# How do I precompile partials for handlebars.js?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars.js and I want to start precompiling everything, but I can't seem to find a way to precompile the partials. The majority of my templates are actually partials. I tried just treating my them like regular templates, but then calling them as a partial doesn't work.

Is there any way to precompile partials, or, alternatively, call one template from within another template?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found an even better method: precompile all your partials as templates, then right before you use them in your code, add this line:

```
Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.templates;
```

The improvements are 1) it's shorter and 2) it doesn't loose any custom helpers you might pass in when calling the parent template.

Comment: This is awesome! What's the secret behind it? why this is not built into the Handlebars?

Thanks anyway :)))))

Comment: The secret is that there isn't really any difference between a partial and a template ;)

Comment: Do you still call the partials within your templates with the normal partial syntax using this method?

Comment: Yes, standard syntax: `{{> partialName}}`, or at least that's what we did at the time. (I no longer work at the company where I implemented this, and I haven't used handlebars templates recently. But that answer is probably still true.)

Comment: Fantastic, a workaround for precompiling handlebars templates for unit testing, will link from https://github.com/hanachin/karma-handlebars-preprocessor/issues/2

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned [here on GitHub](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/374), there has been a `-p` flag added to the Handlebars CLI.

So you can use `handlebars my_partial.handlebars -p -f output.js`

Answer (score 5):

Still not sure about precompiling partials, but this is how to call one template from within another template with help from  this question: [Handlebars helper for template composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537724/handlebars-helper-for-template-composition)

```
// instead of {{> partialName}} use {{partial "templateName"}}
Handlebars.registerHelper('partial', function(templateName,context){
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Handlebars.templates[templateName](this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EBt8R/

Answer (score 5):

I am using HandleBars v3.0.3 and I have partial and not partial templates pre-compiled in one file.

This thread is little bit confusing so I am summarizing the working solution.

- Don't use -p operator while pre-compiling.
- Don't register partial template by Handlebars.registerPartial('myPartial', '{{name}}');
- use Nathan's suggestion of mapping  partial object to templates object by 
  Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.templates;
- Refer partial template by name {{> name}}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by pre compiling all my partials as templates and then adapting Nathans solution

```
// instead of {{> partialName}} use {{partial "templateName"}}
Handlebars.registerHelper('partial', function (templateName) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(JST[templateName](this));
});
```

So for me `Handlebars.templates` became `JST` when i compiled things, i noticed it in my compiled templates file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(let [name, template] of Object.entries(handlebars.partials)) {
    handlebars.partials[name] = handlebars.compile(template);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing all the registered partials I recommend instead explicitly adding the partials, possibly filtering them as well such as:

```js
Object.entries(Handlebars.templates).forEach(([k, v]) => { if ( k.indexOf('partial') != -1 ) Handlebars.partials[k] = v })
```

In this case we only insert precompiled templates that contain "partial" in the name.  This would allow you to either store these in a `partials/` subfolder or within the name such as `some-partial.hbs`