# Handlebars partial documentation unclear

Tags: handlebars.js, partials

So I've read the offical documentation regarding [Handlebars partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html).

It states:

> In order to use a partial, it must be registered via `Handlebars.registerPartial`.
>
> `Handlebars.registerPartial('myPartial', '{{name}}')`
>
> This call will register the myPartial partial. Partials may be precompiled and the precompiled template passed into the second parameter.

It does not explain what `{{name}}` is supposed to be when you're not precompiling anything. I don't want to register inline templates, I have them as separate files in `templates/partials`, e.g. `templates/partials/_header.hbs`. I only need to generate the HTML as part of my build process using `gulp-handlebars`.

The documentation does not cover how to register external files as templates (which I'd assume to be the standard case when using handlebars on the server-side).

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

The section in the documentation you've quoted says:

> Partials may be precompiled and the precompiled template passed into the second parameter.

This means you can replace the `'{{name}}'` with a precompiled partial. This will require you to precompile the partials using the `-p` flag.

You can avoid all that and precompile your templates and partials together without the `-p` flag. (Essentially precompiling the partials as templates). By doing this you won't need to preregister the partials.
A side effect of this is that you'll need to add `Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.templates;` before your code deals with any templates or partials.

This is based on information from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014547/how-do-i-precompile-partials-for-handlebars-js).