# Reusing templates in handlebars

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I am new to JS templating and Handlebars
I have a nested JSON structure, often each parent node is a new object / has different structure so recursion is not the solution I think.

My question is 
Is it possible to call another template from a template in Handlebars?

My background is XSLT

Example:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
  .. call template-2
</script>

<script id="template-2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>{{name2}}</div>
   .. call template-3
</script>

<script id="template-3" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>{{name3}}</div>
</script>
```

.. and so on

Anyone who has some advice?

Best regards,
Bob

Comment: Here is a custom solution from another StackOverflow user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537724/handlebars-helper-for-template-composition

Answer (score 9):

That should be pretty easy using partials, and here is a [pretty good tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers).

Essentially though you just need to define the partial

```
 Handlebars.registerPartial("template-2", $("#template-2").html());
```

And then utilize it

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
  {{> template-2}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a youtube video on partials that explains this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/02J5A3r-Bdk. The video explains creating partials in handlebars in detail and some of the concerns and issues that come a long with and when they are *best* used and when a server-side include might be better.